# I can't install kivy on windows 10 with py3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I can't install kivy on windows 10. What can i do? Here are errors.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
  Using cached kivy-1.9.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4 in c:\users\kenan\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from kivy)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\kenan\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy)
Building wheels for collected packages: kivy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for kivy ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\kenan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\\kivy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp86qekmsbpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  Using distutils

  Detected Cython version 0.23
  User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
  Windows platform detected, force GLEW usage.
  Using this graphics system: OpenGL
  WARNING: A problem occured while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

  WARNING: A problem occured while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

  Build configuration is:
   * use_rpi = 0
   * use_mali = 0
   * use_egl = 0
   * use_opengl_es2 = 0
   * use_opengl_debug = 0
   * use_glew = 1
   * use_sdl2 = 0
   * use_ios = 0
   * use_mesagl = 0
   * use_x11 = 0
   * use_gstreamer = 0
   * use_avfoundation = 0
   * use_osx_frameworks = 0
   * debug_gl = 0
   * debug = False

  Detected compiler is msvc

  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\include -IC:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" /TcC:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\kivy\kivy\graphics\vertex_instructions.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\kivy\kivy\graphics\vertex_instructions.obj
  vertex_instructions.c
  c:\users\kenan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl_redirect.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory
   error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for kivy
  Running setup.py clean for kivy
Failed to build kivy
Installing collected packages: kivy
  Running setup.py install for kivy ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\kenan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\\kivy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-9ucs7wug-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Using distutils

    Detected Cython version 0.23
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Windows platform detected, force GLEW usage.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occured while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occured while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"


    Build configuration is:
     * use_rpi = 0
     * use_mali = 0
     * use_egl = 0
     * use_opengl_es2 = 0
     * use_opengl_debug = 0
     * use_glew = 1
     * use_sdl2 = 0
     * use_ios = 0
     * use_mesagl = 0
     * use_x11 = 0
     * use_gstreamer = 0
     * use_avfoundation = 0
     * use_osx_frameworks = 0
     * debug_gl = 0
     * debug = False
    Detected compiler is msvc
    cythoning C:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\kivy\kivy\graphics/vbo.pyx to C:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\kivy\kivy\graphics\vbo.c
    building 'kivy.graphics.vbo' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\Users
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\Users\kenan
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\Users\kenan\AppData
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\Users\kenan\AppData\Local
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ojxbuh8
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\kivy
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\kivy\kivy
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\kivy\kivy\graphics
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\include -IC:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" /TcC:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\kivy\kivy\graphics\vbo.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\kivy\kivy\graphics\vbo.obj
    vbo.c
    c:\users\kenan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl_redirect.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory
     error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\kenan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\\kivy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-9ucs7wug-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\kenan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9ojxbuh8\kivy\*
```

Answer (score 0):

Kivy now has 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 wheels, no compilation necessary. See [installation documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#nightly-wheel-installation). The error is because you were trying to install Kivy from pip, where is only the **stable** version now (1.9.1), which is a little bit old and the code ***doesn't*** support py3.5 and higher in that state.

---

<s>MSVC needs a little bit of tweaking and patches. The whole instructions are in pull requests, but [those](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4694) are still experimental **only** and there's a need to fix a pointer mismatch (another pull request).</s>

Otherwise Kivy (at least for py3.4 and lower) uses `gcc`. How to compile is written [here](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#use-development-kivy)

However, for casual usage you don't need to compile, because there are wheels. If you read the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html) properly, you'll find out how to install it.

If you encounter `Window` error, search here, there are already answered questions.

<s>There are even unofficial wheels for py3.5 somewhere.</s>

Answer (score 0):

1. Install PIP
2. Upgrade PIP
3. Install Microsoft CPP BUILD TOOLS. Google it, you can find it easily if this [link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126) is broken.
4. Download Kivy Package from
   http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame  You might face
   issues of "Wheel package is not supported". Just look for the
   package with win32 with/without AMD. Still, if you keep getting the
   same error, Just try downloading the different package and follow
   the following steps. Took me to download 3 Packages to get it right.
5. Open CMD
6. Change Directory to Downloads (Or wherever the package is
   downloaded)

   Do `pip install completePackageName.whl`

   Ex: `C:\Users\UserName\Downloads>pip install
   Kivy-1.9.1+sdl2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl`

Comment: You know wheels contain already compiled files, right? That's why installing VC++BT is completely unnecessary.

Comment: this link is dead http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Comment: @Brambor Thanks for the feedback, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi im using py38 and win10 too,

check this https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6563

Anyone recommend run this command, (it works for me)

`pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/`

or try with [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy)