# Cannot install Kivy from/in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, kivy

Win 10 Pro (64bit), Python 3.6.0, Pyhon 2017.1, Cython version 0.23, Visual Studio 2015

I am unable to install Kivy from within PyCharm (Settings/Project Interpreter) and have tried a couple of things such as:
- Installing Visual Studio 2015 
- Installing Cython 0.23
I've read in another post the use of 'wheels' ([I can't install kivy on windows 10 with py3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40782764/i-cant-install-kivy-on-windows-10-with-py3-5)) but can any one tell me how to apply that to PyCharm?

Below the error message:

Collecting Kivy
  Using cached kivy-1.9.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4 in c:\users\Stal\just atrial django project\lib\site-packages (from Kivy)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\Stal\just atrial django project\lib\site-packages (from Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->Kivy)
Installing collected packages: Kivy
  Running setup.py install for Kivy: started
    Running setup.py install for Kivy: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command "C:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\Scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-043s8ql1-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\include\site\python3.6\Kivy":
    Using distutils

```
Detected Cython version 0.23
User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
Windows platform detected, force GLEW usage.
Using this graphics system: OpenGL
WARNING: A problem occured while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

WARNING: A problem occured while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kivy
copying kivy\animation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kivy
copying kivy\app.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kivy
copying kivy\atlas.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kivy
copying kivy\base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kivy
```

[...............   edited for brevity .................... ]
    copying kivy\cache.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kivy
       Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy_event.cp36-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy_event.cp36-win_amd64.exp

```
Generating code
Finished generating code
cythoning C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.pyx to C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.c
building 'kivy.weakproxy' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\include" -IC:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -IC:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" /TcC:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.obj
weakproxy.c
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.c(10691): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.c(10709): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.c(10727): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.c(10901): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.c(10919): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.c(10937): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\libs" /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36 "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\PCbuild\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_weakproxy build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kivy\weakproxy.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.cp36-win_amd64.lib
weakproxy.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_weakproxy' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.cp36-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\weakproxy.cp36-win_amd64.exp
Generating code
Finished generating code
cythoning C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.pyx to C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.c
building 'kivy.properties' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\include" -IC:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -IC:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" /TcC:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.obj
properties.c
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.c(2303): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.c(2438): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.c(2467): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.c(2496): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.c(35272): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.c(35290): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.c(35308): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.c(35508): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.c(35526): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.c(35544): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\libs" /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36 "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\PCbuild\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_properties build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kivy\properties.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.cp36-win_amd64.lib
properties.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_properties' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.cp36-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\properties.cp36-win_amd64.exp
Generating code
Finished generating code
cythoning C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics/buffer.pyx to C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.c
building 'kivy.graphics.buffer' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\include" -IC:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -IC:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" /TcC:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.obj
buffer.c
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.c(2718): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.c(2736): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.c(2754): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.c(2954): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.c(2972): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.c(2990): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\libs" /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36 "/LIBPATH:C:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\PCbuild\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_buffer build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kivy\graphics\buffer.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.cp36-win_amd64.lib
buffer.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_buffer' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.cp36-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\buffer.cp36-win_amd64.exp
Generating code
Finished generating code
cythoning C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics/context.pyx to C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\context.c
building 'kivy.graphics.context' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\include" -IC:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include -IC:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.14393.0\winrt" /TcC:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\context.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\kivy\graphics\context.obj
context.c
c:\users\Stal\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl_redirect.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL/glew.h': No such file or directory
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
```

Command ""C:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\Scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-043s8ql1-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\Stal\Just atrial Django project\include\site\python3.6\Kivy"" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Stal\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Kivy\

Comment: The problem is called RTFM; kivi has great install manuals, if you go and read it says that it works with python up to 3.4 but not with 3.5 and 3.6 ....

Answer (score 2):

Kivy should be installed traditionally using pip. Making a complex answer short: Kivy doesn't play nice with virtual environments due to dependencies your specific error is due to Kivy not being able to communicate with OpenGL, an essential dependency of Kivy.

WINDOWS (cmd):

```
pip install --upgrade kivy
```

LINUX (terminal):

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade kivy
```

then confirm it was properly installed simply by:

```
>> python3
>> import Kivy
```

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with a complex process if an easy approach is available. 
Bypass the cython installation by using the nightly wheels. See https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html

You do the installation from the windows command prompt. Not the python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

What it worked with me and Windows 10 was:

```
python -m pip install kivy
```

Answer (score -1):

just install this in terminal:-
`$ pip install kivy-deps.gstreamer3`

try to install this too in terminal, if the kivy module doesn't works:-
`$ pip install kivy-deps.sdl2`
`$ pip install kivy-deps.glew`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).